# Get coordinates of imageview during animation android

Tags: android, animation, position, coordinates, delay

I am trying make an animation of an imageView from left to right and get it back from right to left but I also want to get the position of the imageview while its animation from the following code. I want to use the coordinates from origin to display in my app. Please tell me how to do this. Following is the code I am using to animate and move position of imageview.

```
 Animation anx = new TranslateAnimation(0,100,0, 0);
                anx.setDuration(2000);
                anx.setFillAfter(true);
                myImage.startAnimation(anx);
```

Is there a function like getX() and getY() to get position.

Comment: If your problem is solved, could you post the solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Have u tried to set animation listener and starting a runnable when the animation starts to check the image getx , gety every milliseconds u want and stop it after the animation ends